# Isso é um operador no javascript? =>

Tags: javascript

Tou aprendendo JS e baixei um package do Atom e fui ver o codigo dele, encontrei isso, que acho que é um operador `=>` mas gostaria de tirar essa duvida

Comment: Olá @vinibudd, segue o link : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_operators